# Matlab: trouble converting symbolic expression to numeric

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I've noticed that after the substitution of numeric `'float'` values in a symbolic matrix, the conversion is in a fractional form with very large values, that I want to avoid:

```
A=(uvw(1,:)-bMat(1,:)).^2+(uvw(2,:)-bMat(2,:)).^2+(uvw(3,:)-bMat(3,:)).^2-legStroke.^2;
A=subs(A,[x,y,z,phi,theta,psi],...
         [1.37,0.0,0.0,degtorad(0.0),degtorad(-1.32),degtorad(0.0)]);
A=simplify(A)
```

and I get as result the following:

```
A=[((9004809005642893*p1x)/9007199254740992 - b1x + 137/100)^2-l1^2 +(44086462975326147772185208371001*p1x^2)/83076749736557242056487941267521536 + ...
```

I tried to use `sym(A,'d')` or similar, following some tips from the web, but I got this error message:

> Error in sym>tomupad (line 2232)
>       assumptions(S,x.s,a);

Comment: Your code is not runnable. Please edit your question to define all values, numeric or symbolic and any assumptions you've specified so that we can replicate your issue. It doesn't need to be the precise code you're using, just something short that exhibits the identical problems. Also, what `version` of Matlab are you using? Also, FYI, `degtorad` is vectorized, so you can simply do `degtorad([0.0 -1.32 0.0])`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply `sym(A,'d')` if `A` is already a symbolic expression (i.e., in terms of unknown symbolic variables, class `sym` or `symfun`). The purpose of `sym(A,'d')` is to convert a numeric values and arrays into symbolic form.

You have two options.

**1.** Use something like `sym(A,'d')` to convert your numeric values to inexact symbolic decimal form *before* they are incorporated into your symbolic expressions. This will result in a loss of accuracy in some cases.

**2.** Convert your exact symbolic expression to floating-point form at the very end using [variable precision arithmetic](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html), i.e., `vpa(A)`. This method should be more accurate as your symbolic calculations will be be done exactly (you still need be careful how you do your initial conversion to symbolic, however).